# Change the type of feature from string to float using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am connecting to a MongoDB using the following client:

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv:...")
```

and I would like to convert the feature "imdbRating" to float from string, throughout the whole DB.

How can I achieve that?
[image: p]

Comment: Read each document, cast the value to desired type, write new value to db.

Comment: Thank you; in code how would it be?

Comment: You could use `update` with a pipeline and the `$toString` operator

Answer (score 1):

The below script will do the trick.

```
client = MongoClient()

col = client['<DB-Name>']['<Coollection-Name>']

count = 0
for cursor in col.find({}, {"imdbRating": 1}):
    col.update_one({
        "_id": cursor["_id"]
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "imdbRating": float(cursor["imdbRating"])
        }
    })
    count += 1
    print("\r", count, end='')
print("\n\nDONE!!!")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; however, it seems to be too slowly, given the for loop; is there a way to speed it up? Probably with update_many()? @hhharsha36

Comment: @Belly Buster has an alternative solution posted, give it a try. Reach out to me again if you are facing difficulty implementing it. Additionally, which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I have, but I encountered an issue (described in the comment)

Answer (score 0):

> NB This answer uses the [pipeline operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) in `update_many()`
> which requires **MongoDB 4.2 or later**.

Firstly just to point out there is no "float" type in MongoDB, your choice is `double` or `decimal`.

You can do the update in one line, with a further line to loop all the collections.

```
for col in db.list_collection_names():
    db[col].update_many({'imdbRating': {'$exists': True, '$type': 'string'}}, [{'$set': {'imdbRating': { '$toDouble': '$imdbRating'}}}])
```

If you want a `decimal` instead of a `double` replace `$toDouble` with `$toDecimal`.

Example with test data setup:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps

# Database connection and test data setup; 10 collections each with 10 records

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

for col in range(10):
    for record in range(10):
        db[f'col{col}'].insert_one({'Record': str(record), 'imdbRating': str(record)})

print('Before\n' + dumps(db.col9.find_one({}, {'_id': 0}), indent=4))

# Update all imdbRating to float from string in all collections

for col in db.list_collection_names():
    db[col].update_many({'imdbRating': {'$exists': True, '$type': 'string'}}, [{'$set': {'imdbRating': { '$toDouble': '$imdbRating'}}}])

print('After\n' + dumps(db.col9.find_one({}, {'_id': 0}), indent=4))
```

Gives:

```
Before
{
    "Record": "0",
    "imdbRating": "0"
}
After
{
    "Record": "0",
    "imdbRating": 0.0
}
```

Comment: Thank you; it seems to work until it encounters an empty value ""; is there a way to solve this issue: WriteError: Failed to parse number '' in $convert with no onError value: Empty string?

Comment: Add the below condition in the update query filter section and see if it helps  ```db[col].update_many({'imdbRating': {'$exists': True, '$type': 'string', "$ne": ""}}, [{'$set': {'imdbRating': {'$toDouble': '$imdbRating'}}}])```